# Wifi - no reception

Tags: wireless-networking

My Laptop will not connect to Xerox Phaser printer 6022 by WiFi. I recently changed from a DSL modem and router to a Fios all-in-one modem & router.  Printer status says: `WiFi - no reception`.

How can I correct this issue? Thanks for any replies

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Xerox Phaser printer isn't attached to your wifi network. You'll need to change the settings on the printer to match whatever the network access settings of your modem/router are.